# SQL Server 2008 Column Identity based on years

Tags: sql-server-2008, reset, identity

I have an existing VFP database (dbf files) and i want  to migrate it to SQL Server 2008.

The problem is :

Table « Invoices » in my VFP database have primary key having  the following  format :

```
                                    year+counter
```

for example :  for year 2013 -->  201300001, 201300002,…,20130000n
               for year 2012 --> 201200001, 201200002, 201200003,…..20120000n
etc.

the counter must be reset at the beginning of every year

to compute these sequences, i get a counter from another dbf table, i increment it and i save. 
Here i have to take care of conflicts and risk of duplicate keys.
I heard a lot on identity column and how it avoid me concurrency.  Because sql itself take care of computing identity column.

Based on what was said, is there a solution for this ?

Thank you.

hi user2511414, I tried Instead of Trigger as follows :

```
CREATE TRIGGER AutoIncrement_Trigger ON dblease.dbo.testAutoinc
instead OF INSERT AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @ach CHAR
 DECLARE @ch CHAR
 DECLARE @num INT
 DECLARE @an  INT

 SET     @an  = year(GetDate())
 SET     @ach = Convert(char(4),@an)
select  @num = SUBSTRING(MAX(id),5,5) FROM dblease.dbo.testAutoinc having     SUBSTRING(MAX(id),1,4) = @ach

 INSERT INTO dblease.dbo.testAutoinc (id,designation,date) SELECT (@ach+CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),(@num+1))),inserted.designation, GetDate() FROM inserted
END
```

But when execute the following query :

```
     insert into testAutoinc (designation, date) values ('TEST','25/06/2013');
```

i get the following error :
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id',
table 'dblease.dbo.testAutoinc'; column does not allow nulls.
INSERT fails.  The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a column for the year and one for your counter - you can then use a computed column to concatenate them into your year+counter field. This can then be your primary key, or, you might want to consider a surrogate key as your primary and place a unique index on your year+counter field.

To generate the counter number you could use a trigger, or force inserts to go via a stored procedure. Depends on whether you need to insert several rows at a time or its always one-at-a-time.

You could use an identity column for your counter and reset it at the beginning of each year (DBCC CHECKIDENT RESEED) which would avoid having to use a trigger or proc, but would mean you (or your successors) would have to remember to reset it.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[YearCounter](
    [YearId] [int] NULL,
    [Counter] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Yc1]  AS (CONVERT([varchar](4),[YearId])+CONVERT([varchar](10),[Counter]))
)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[YearCounter] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_YearCounter_YearId]  DEFAULT (datepart(year,getdate())) FOR [YearId]
```